# Prolog: Why is this predicate showing up as true?

Tags: prolog, logic

so I have written this predicate in SWI prolog with the goal of having it succeed if its argument is an expression without
any atoms

```
no_atoms(X):- var(X), !, fail.
no_atoms(X):- atom(X); number(X).
no_atoms(X+Y):- no_atoms(X), no_atoms(Y).
no_atoms(X-Y):- no_atoms(X), no_atoms(Y).
```

to test this no_atoms(5-(3+x)) should come as false and no_atoms((12+8)-7) should be true, however both come up as true and im not sure whats wrong?

Comment: lower case `x` is an atom. Upper case `X` is a variable which may be unbound. You may try querying `no_atoms(5-(3+X))` with unbound upper case `X`.

Comment: thank you, its false with the upper case, but is there a way to prove it being false while querying it with the lower case x?

Comment: you would have to check which atoms are your expression variables, for example single letters. `var/1` is to check whether the argument is currently an unbound variable

Comment: This is so confusing to me. What is an "expression"? Is `X*Y`not an "expression"? What does "without any atoms" mean if the atoms`+` and `-` don't count?

Answer (score 1):

If a goal `no_atoms(X)` must succeed when term `X` has no atoms, then the condition `atom(X)` in the second clause of the definition of `no_atoms/1` must be eliminated.

```
no_atoms(X) :- var(X), !, fail.
no_atoms(X) :- number(X).
no_atoms(X+Y) :- no_atoms(X), no_atoms(Y).
no_atoms(X-Y) :- no_atoms(X), no_atoms(Y).
```

Running example:

```
?- no_atoms((12+8)-7).
true.

?- no_atoms(5-(3+x)).
false.

?- no_atoms(X).
false.
```

In addition, since a *variable is not an atom*, perhaps a better definition is as follows:

```
no_atoms(X) :- var(X), !.
no_atoms(X) :- number(X).
no_atoms(X+Y) :- no_atoms(X), no_atoms(Y).
no_atoms(X-Y) :- no_atoms(X), no_atoms(Y).
```

Running example:

```
?- no_atoms((12+8)-7).
true.

?- no_atoms(5-(3+x)).
false.

?- no_atoms(X).
true.
```